# SSTP connection established, but doesn't work

Tags: networking, vpn, ppp

I need to connect Ubuntu 14.04 (64) server  to Windows VPN.

I've installed [sstp client](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/files/sstp-client/1.0.10/sstp-client_1.0.10-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) `sstp-client (1.0.10)` [with lib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/files/sstp-client/1.0.10/libsstp-client0_1.0.10-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb), setup `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` and a `/etc/ppp/peers/mypeer`

Seems, on `sudo pon mypeer` the server connects to VPN.

```
$ sudo plog
Jun  8 04:20:08 sg2 pppd[61835]: local  IP address 10.10.99.24
Jun  8 04:20:08 sg2 pppd[61835]: remote IP address 10.10.99.1
Jun  8 04:20:08 sg2 pppd[61835]: primary   DNS address 10.10.10.9
Jun  8 04:20:08 sg2 pppd[61835]: secondary DNS address 10.10.10.10
Jun  8 04:20:08 sg2 pppd[61835]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 62219)
Jun  8 04:20:08 sg2 pppd[61835]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 62219), status = 0x0
Jun  8 04:20:10 sg2 pppd[61835]: sent [CCP ConfReq id=0xb]
Jun  8 04:20:10 sg2 pppd[61835]: rcvd [CCP TermAck id=0xb]
Jun  8 04:20:10 sg2 pppd[61835]: sent [CCP TermReq id=0xc"No compression negotiated"]
Jun  8 04:20:10 sg2 pppd[61835]: rcvd [CCP TermAck id=0xc"No compression negotiated"]
```

routes before connecting:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.3     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and routes after connection:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.3     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.99.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The difference is:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.99.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

As I understand, that defines the route to the host 10.10.99.1 over ppp0 interface

**Issues I can't resolve**

**1.** I can't ping that host, despite I can ping it from Windows workstation connected to the same VPN. How to make it work?

**2.** Also if I manually define a new route:

```
$ sudo route add -net 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.10.99.1
```

I see the new route:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.0.0       10.10.99.1      255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 ppp0
```

But I still cannot access any host in VPN. What is wrong with my route?

**UPDATE - ping**

```
$ ping -c 3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=2.92 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=2.60 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=2.99 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.603/2.839/2.994/0.169 ms
$ ping -c 3 -I ppp0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.10.99.2 ppp0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

**UPDATE - version**

Tried also `sstp client (1.0.9)` with no luck

Comment: Do DNS queries resolve?  Can you ping out to another IP address (8.8.8.8 for example)?

Comment: Yes I can ping 8.8.8.8 through eth0, but not through ppp0. See **UPDATE  - ping** above

Answer (score 0):

Add this route using the command line or the VPN Connection Settings:

```
route add -net 10.10.99.24 netmask 255.255.255.255 metric 1 gw 192.168.0.3
```